# Polymer 1.0: paper-tooltip not working

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I can't seem to get `<paper-tooltip>` element to work for me.

[Here is my JSBin](http://jsbin.com/panajubuzu/edit?html,output).

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="http://polymer-magic-server.appspot.com/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style></style>
        <div class="with-tooltip" tabindex="0">
          <input type="checkbox">Oxygen
          <paper-tooltip>Atomic number: 8</paper-tooltip>
        </div>
        <paper-icon-button id="heart" icon="favorite" alt="heart"></paper-icon-button>
        <paper-icon-button id="back" icon="arrow-back" alt="go back"></paper-icon-button>
        <paper-icon-button id="fwd" icon="arrow-forward" alt="go forward"></paper-icon-button>
        <paper-tooltip for="heart" margin-top="0">&lt;3 &lt;3 &lt;3 </paper-tooltip>
        <paper-tooltip for="back" margin-top="0">halp I am trapped in a tooltip</paper-tooltip>
        <paper-tooltip for="fwd" margin-top="0">back to the future</paper-tooltip>
    </template>
    <script>

      // only need this when both (1) in the main document and
      // (2) on non-Chrome browsers
      addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {

        Polymer({
          is: "x-foo"
        });

      });

    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <x-foo></x-foo>

</body>
```

Comment: You're doing every correctly, you just have to import `paper-icon-button`, `iron-icons`, and `paper-tooltip`. [Here's a working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/covuro/2/edit?html,output)

Comment: @KevinAshcraft: Ah. Thanks. I didn't realize I still had to import each element individually. I guess I didn't understand how to use the `magic-server` thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary from comments:

Per @kevinashcraft:

> You have to import paper-icon-button, iron-icons, and paper-tooltip. [Here's a working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/covuro/2/edit?html,output).